# Java android open street map CustomInfoWindow close infoWindow when click in image

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

This is how I create a CustomInfoWindow :

```
private class CustomInfoWindow extends MarkerInfoWindow {
POI mSelectedPoi;

CustomInfoWindow(MapView mapView) {
    super(R.layout.bonuspack_bubble, mapView);
    Button btn = (Button) (mView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_moreinfo));
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Singleton si = Singleton.getInstance();
            ObjectDefExtends obj = si.getCurrentObject();
            if (obj != null && Singleton.getInstance().getListaVisible().size() > 0) {
                ObjectDefExtends currentObject = si.getCurrentObject();
                double latitude = currentObject.lat;
                double longitude = currentObject.lon;
                String label = currentObject.name;
                String uriBegin = "geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude;
                String query = latitude + "," + longitude + "(" + label + ")";
                String encodedQuery = Uri.encode(query);
                String uriString = uriBegin + "?q=" + encodedQuery + "&z=16";
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onOpen(Object item) {
    super.onOpen(item);
    mView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_moreinfo).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Marker marker = (Marker) item;
    mSelectedPoi = (POI) marker.getRelatedObject();
}
}
```

And I try do it this when I click btn and go to new intent I want to close this InfoWindow. When I go back  from this intent all the time I see this InfoWindow

Answer (score 0):

Call `finish();` after `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: When I call a finish I see black window and in log I see : Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.smok.maps/com.smok.maps.logowanie.LoginActivity}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.